# vector behavior differ between MSVC and GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    auto vsize = v.capacity();
    for (int tmp = 0; tmp < 1000;tmp++)
    {
        v.push_back(tmp);
        if(vsize!=v.capacity())
        {
            vsize = v.capacity();
            cout << "capacity changed : " << vsize << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[compiled by MSVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8eIZ.png)

[compiled by GCC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpTeq.png)

vector's capacity should be previous double, why MSVC not work in this?

Comment: "vector's capacity should be previous double" you should stop to deduce requirements from behavior, but rely on documentation instead

Comment: There is a smurf-load of research on just how much capacity should increase on a resize, and no one agrees on exactly how much.  I recall that the general consensus was somewhere between 1.5 and 2 is best for most cases. Looks like MSVC is putting a bit more thought into it, but how much that helps needs to be profiled on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Two related questions popped up yesterday that may also be of interest to you: [Why are C++ STL vectors 1000x slower when doing many reserves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535727/why-are-c-stl-vectors-1000x-slower-when-doing-many-reserves) and [Why does std::vector reserve not “double” its capacity, while resize does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537812/why-does-stdvector-reserve-not-double-its-capacity-while-resize-does)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> vector's capacity should be previous double, why MSVC not work in this?

Where did you get that from?

That's implementation specific behavior. There's nothing said in the standard how `capacity()` should change after calling `push_back()`, besides it must guarantee the `std::vector` has *enough* (not *double* than before) space allocated.

Answer (score 1):

> vector's capacity should be previous double

That is wrong.  The only requirement is that `vector::push_back` performs amortized O(1) copies.  That can be achieved by multiplying the capacity by a constant factor every time a reallocation is required - but that constant does not have to be 2 (it does have to be greater than 1).  GCC uses 2, MSVC uses 3/2.  (The advantage of the latter is that it uses less space, at a cost of more copies)

Answer (score 0):

"vector's capacity should be previous double". No it should not. How and by how much a `std::vector` increases its capacity when it grows is *implementation defined*.

This means that every implementation is free to do its own thing. It can double the size, increase it by 2, increase it 10-fold or whatever. From your point, as a user of the container, you cannot know and you are not supposed to care.