# Comparing pushing data (1 million numbers) with and without prior resizing in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

Comparing pushing data (1 million numbers) with and without prior resizing into  std::vector. To my amusement , I found the later ( without resizing) to be faster , which is contrary to expectation. What happened ? I am using MS VC++ 2017 compiler.

```
double times = 1000000;

vector<double> vec1;
auto tp_start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (double i=0; i < times; i++)
{
    vec1.push_back(i);
}
auto lapse = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - tp_start;
cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(lapse).count() << " ms : push without prior resize  \n"; // 501 ms

vector<double> vec2;
vec2.resize(times);  // resizing
tp_start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();    
for (double i = 0; i < times; i++)
{     
       vec2[i]  = i; //fastest
      // vec2.push_back(i); //slower
}
lapse = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - tp_start;
cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(lapse).count() << " ms : push with prior resizing  \n"; // 518 ms , shouldn't this be faster theoritically
```

**Edited:**

After this change: vec2.resize(times); it works faster

After this change: vec2.reserve(times); it works even faster

After this change: vec2[i] = i; becomes super fast

Any advise what is the best practice?

**Edited 2**  ( compiler in optimized mode)

10 million data :

```
 120ms : 41ms   reserve & pushback

 121ms : 35ms   resize & vec[i]
```

100 million data :

```
 1356ms : 427ms   reserve & pushback

 1345ms : 364ms   resize & vec[i]
```

**vec[i] still wins**

Comment: You want `.reserve()`, not `.resize()`. Your second vector ends up containing two million elements.  Also; what are your compiler flags/options? Make sure you are testing an optimized build, not a debug build.

Comment: As for the argument to the `resize` (or `reserve`) calls, it's the number of *elements*, not the size in bytes. If the size of `double` is `8` (which is common) then you will (with your current code) have *nine* million elements in the vector, of which the first eight million will all be zero.

Comment: You should also reserve `times` amount of items, not 4-8x as much.

Comment: With a corrected example, I get expected results: http://quick-bench.com/HLMeKeT0G67VgUYsMgyb1jU2vsE

Comment: Plz see question partially edited.

Comment: @ark1974 `vec2.resize(sizeof(double)* times);  // resizing` is wrong, should be `resize(times)`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535727/why-are-c-stl-vectors-1000x-slower-when-doing-many-reserves

Comment: @Mikhail: Edited already

Comment: And there's also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537812/why-does-stdvector-reserve-not-double-its-capacity-while-resize-does

Comment: @ark1974 *I am using MS VC++ 2017 compiler.* -- I see no indication of whether you are testing an optimized version of your code.  If you're running a "debug" or unoptimized version, your timing results are worthless.   The vector class in Visual Studio has iterator checks in debug versions, and these checks slow the code down significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After this change: vec2.resize(times); it works faster

I think maybe that's because after the `resize` the `vec2` actually holds `2*times` space,so it does not need reallocating in later `push_back`.

> After this change: vec2.reserve(times); it works even faster

this version does not need reallocating,so it's better than the first one.

> After this change: vec2[i] = i; becomes super fast

this directly place the element on its position,without any redundant operations compared with `push_back`

---

## origin answer

You should do like:

```
vector<double> vec2;
vec2.resize(sizeof(double)* times);  // this directly chage the size(),with capacity() also changed.
tp_start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();    
for (double i = 0; i < times; i++)
{
    vec2[i]=i;//not push_back
}
```

If you still use `push_back` in this situation,it does not have any efficiency.

And in your example with `resize`,the size of `vec2` is larger than `vec1`,which needs more time to reallocate its memory,and takes more time to do `push_back`.By the way it's better to do `reserve(n)` in your case.

Comment: I think you are right. Why it doesn't apply to push_back () in the resized vector.

Comment: @bigxiao `reserve` allocates memory and sets the capacity, but not the size. `resize` both allocates memory, sets the capacity *and* the size. The size must always be less than or equal to the capacity.

Comment: *"this chage the size(),not capacity()"* - So what if the size requested is greater than the capacity?

Comment: @StoryTeller,@Some programmer dude ,Thanks for your reminding.

Comment: @bigxiao: +1 for the vec2[i] = i; But reserve() don't work in this case.

Comment: @ark1974 `vec2[i]=i` needs `resize`,which will allocate memory,initialize the elements and thus take some extra time(not measured in your example). I think `reserve()` is better than your first version without `resize` and `reserve`.